# Multiple email validation in single field with Formik

Tags: reactjs, formik

Is there any way to validate multiple email id in Formik without using Yup.
I have been using the following code currently for single email validation:

```
    if (!values.cc) {
        errors.cc = "Required";
    } else if (!/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i.test(values.cc)) {
        errors.cc = "Invalid email address";
    }
```

The emails will be separated by space.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your own custom validation function for that here is an

Formik Field:

```
<Field
    type="text"
    name="email"
    placeholder="Enter Your Email Address"
    validate={(event) => Validators.customFieldLevelValidation(event, [Validators.required, Validators.email, Validators.aol])} />
```

Custom Validator Class:

```
class Validators {
    static customFieldLevelValidation = (value, validations) => {
        for (let validation of validations) {
            const result = validation(value);
            if (result) {
                return result;
            }
        }
        return null;
    };

    static required = value => (value ? undefined : 'Required');

    static email = value =>
        value && !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{1,100}$/i.test(value)
            ? 'Invalid email address'
            : undefined;

    static aol = value =>
        value && /.+@aol\.com/.test(value)
            ? 'Really? You still use AOL for your email?'
            : undefined;

    static alphaNumeric = value =>
        value && /[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/i.test(value)
            ? 'Only alphanumeric characters'
            : undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use yup it's very helpful :)

```
 email: Yup.string()
        .email("Format de l'email est invalide")
        .matches(
            /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
            , "Format de l'email est invalide")
        .required("Obligatoire!"),
```

Comment: Yes! Didn't use it because this was the only validation left. Will use it the next time.

Answer (score 0):

I have done the validation using the following code, in this case the user need to enter multiple emails by separating them with a comma.

```
        if (!values.cc) {
              errors.cc = "Required";
            } else {
              let emailList = values.cc.split(",");
              emailList.forEach((email) => {
                if (
                  !/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,6}$/i.test(email)
                ) {
                  errors.cc =
                    "Please provide a valid email. In case of multiple emails, seperate them with a comma (,) ";
                }
              });
            }
```